# E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-rqt_reconfigure

Tags: openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS hydro.I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](http://wg-perception.github.io/ork_tutorials/tutorial02/tutorial.html)

when i type:

```
 sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rviz ros-hydro-rqt_reconfigure ros-hydro-openni*
```

i get the following output:

```
    asaad@VAIO:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rviz ros-hydro-rqt_reconfigure ros-hydro-openni*
    [sudo] password for asaad: 
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Note, selecting 'ros-hydro-openni-tracker' for regex 'ros-hydro-openni*'
    Note, selecting 'ros-hydro-openni2-launch' for regex 'ros-hydro-openni*'
    Note, selecting 'ros-hydro-openni2-camera' for regex 'ros-hydro-openni*'
    Note, selecting 'ros-hydro-openni-launch' for regex 'ros-hydro-openni*'
    Note, selecting 'ros-hydro-openni-camera' for regex 'ros-hydro-openni*'
    Note, selecting 'ros-hydro-openni-tracker-jsk-patch' for regex 'ros-hydro-openni*'
    E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-rqt_reconfigure
    asaad@VAIO:~$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220823/e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-hydro-rqt_reconfigure/) by [Asaad Irfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23193/asaad-irfan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please try  `ros-hydro-rqt-reconfigure` . We use **dashes** instead of **underscores** in debian package names.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asaad Irfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23193/asaad-irfan/) on 2015-11-12**:
this solves the problem. Thank you. P.S All my packages were the newest versions already.